# IntelliJ IDEA Hotkey for comment does not work with Scala

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

None of the hotkeys (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Slash</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Divide</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Slash</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Divide</kbd>) as mentioned [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/keyboard-shortcuts-you-cannot-miss.html) doesn't work with my IntelliJ IDEA 11.1.2. Installation under Windows 7, 64 Bit. I use a German keyboard layout.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Tip: `Ctrl+Shift+A` and then type _comment_ to see the actions and current keybindings.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This issue is specific to your keyboard layout, you need to change the **Comment with line comment** and **Comment with block comment** shortcuts in `Settings` | `Keymap`.

Comment: PhpStorm -> Preferences -> Appearance & Behavior -> Keymap -> Main menu -> Code -> Comment with Line Comment

Comment: how do i have to change it?

Comment: don't change it. Just click `Add keyboard shortcut` and choose whatever you want. In this case, you can also use `ctrl+/` when you connect keyboard with numpad to your laptop.

Comment: So it means those shortcuts never work when I don't have any numpad? How am I suppose to do if don't have one? I am suppose to change all the shortcuts one by one?

Comment: This is not really a solution to not working shortcut problem.

Answer (score 14):

If you do not want to change your keymap, you can alternatively use the <kbd>÷</kbd> - Button on the **Numpad** of your keyboard. The <kbd>÷</kbd> - Button represents a **/** on German (and probably most others) -Keyboard Layouts too.

Therefore <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>÷</kbd>(Numpad) and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>÷</kbd>(Numpad) work.

The good part is, that this will work on machines of other developers who haven't remaped their keymap too.

*Edit (see comments below):*
In case your keyboard does not offer a Numpad, your keyboard-layout might offer you a way to emulate a Numpad (for exmaple using a <kbd>Fn</kbd>-key).

Comment: Many of the machines that do not offer a Numpad, are able to emulate it using an extra key (often [Fn]).
This makes it a bit harder since you have to press an extra button. But it still works without altering the keymap. Often the [Fn]-keyis right next to the [Ctrl]-key making it easier to grab.
This will vary between different keyboard layouts but as an example [Fn]+[Ctrl]+[0] will work on some/many notebooks.
If your machine does not support Numpad-emulation, CracyCoders answer works on any machine.