# Shortcuts in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

I have changed the IDE I'm working with form Netbeans to IntelliJ. 
My question right now is, why do the shortcuts don't work.
I want to comment out with "crtl+shift+/" but nothing happens. Is there any bug? Can I import the shortcuts form Netbeans?

Thx for your help.

Comment: Some default shortcuts don't work if you have a non standard keyboard layout. For example, if using a Swedish keyboard layout you have to remap the comment out actions since the "/" character is accessed by pressing "shift-7" and you cannot press "ctrl+shift-shift-7".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to "File" -> "Settings" -> "Keymap" and chose the keymap that you want to use from the "Keymaps" dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to change your keymap or have to work on the machine of somebody else you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad ÷</kbd> and  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>÷</kbd>.

In case you have a keyboard without a numpad it might be possible to emulate the numpad on your keyboard (often using the <kbd>Fn</kbd>-key).

[See also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10897136/intellij-idea-hotkey-for-comment-does-not-work-with-scala/25911213#25911213)