# What IntelliJ stroke is not already used?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I have the same issue with IntelliJ as many others: [IntelliJ IDEA Hotkey for comment does not work with Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10897136/intellij-idea-hotkey-for-comment-does-not-work-with-scala) Having a German keyboard I cannot use the strokes for commenting and I would like to use different stroke for the two commenting shortcuts. Using a keyboard  I cannot use the numpad, because I don't have one. However I cannot find a stroke combination that isn't already used. What stroke combination is not used by IntelliJ?

Btw: I am using the KDE layout. I am programming mostly Scala.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try to assign a hotkey, Intellij will warn you if it's already in use and what it's used for.  It's up to you to decide what combinations work best for you.

Comment: I have been trying for a while now to find a combination of strokes that is still free, but haven't found any. Thus my issue is finding any at all.

Comment: I suspect that there are many existing combinations that you are not currently using these are as good as free and you can overwrite them.  Typically most of the convenient ones are taken but you can assign to something else.  If you must pick a new one, hold down a few modifiers (ctrl, alt, shift) and try things until you find one you like, there are many open.  If you absolutely need a recommendation ctrl+alt+D is unused.

Comment: Things is: Usually I am not using any keystrokes - because I cannot remember them. But I want to change that. I just started learning IntelliJ. Thus I do not know yet which am going to like and which not. However ctrl+alt+D is great, because this is very similar to ctrl+shift+D which is used by Kile.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+[digit] shortcuts are usually free

Comment: Thanks - not all are, but some. After trying out, I actually ended up ctrl+alt+0 and ctrl+alt+ß - let's see if that will stick with me.